# Не правильное значение position элемента при неактивной вкладке jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Добрый день всем, я не знаю как получить правильное значение элемента на неактивной вкладке, я понимаю, что это сам ui меняет позицию элемента, но не хватает внимания и могзов получить верное значение именно из html. Если кто-то сталкивался или хотябы есть идеи, то буду очень благодарен.

html:

```
>     <div id="tabs">
>                 <ul>
>                     <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
>                     <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
>                     <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
>                 </ul>
>                 <div id="tabs-1">
>                     <p id="t1">text 1</p>
>                 </div>
>                 <div id="tabs-2">
>                     <p id="t2">text 3</p>
>                 </div>
>                 <div id="tabs-3">
>                     <p id="t3">text 3</p>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>     <input type="button" value="getPosition" 
> onclick="getP();"/>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({active: 0});

    // set position
    $('#t1').css('position', 'absolute');
    $('#t2').css('position', 'absolute');
    $('#t3').css('position', 'absolute');

    // set top
    $('#t1').css('top', '50px');
    $('#t2').css('top', '70px');
    $('#t3').css('top', '90px');

    // set left
    $('#t1').css('left', '100px');
    $('#t2').css('left', '200px');
    $('#t3').css('left', '300px');

});

function getP() {
    var pos1 = $('#t1').position();
    var pos2 = $('#t2').position();
    var pos3 = $('#t3').position();

    alert('t1: top='+pos1.top+' left='+pos1.left+' t2: top='+pos2.top+' left='+pos2.left+' t3: top='+pos3.top+' left='+pos3.left);
}
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/xnmHj/

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо, вопрос решен получением css свойств

```
top='+$('#t1').css('top')
```

и т.д.

Вот рабочий вариант

http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/xnmHj/1/